# I am receiving a "cannot initialize a parameter of type" error with theos

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, theos

I am getting this error while trying to compile a those project. The error is

> "Tweak.xm:37:21: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'UIView
>   * _Nonnull' with an
>         lvalue of type 'UITapGestureRecognizer *' [content addSubview:singleTap];"

this is the image of my error [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPpgQ.png)

Comment: Update your question with the actual code causing the issue. Provide details about the data types of all variables involved.

Comment: It appears like you are trying to add a tap gesture recognizer as a subview. Why?

Comment: singleTap is not a UIView to add it as subview, use addGestureRecogniser!!!!

Comment: this is the whole error. tell me if you need me to send you the code for the tweak.

Comment: Tweak.xm:37:21: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'UIView * _Nonnull' with an
      lvalue of type 'UITapGestureRecognizer *'
[content addSubview:singleTap];

Answer (score 1):

About your comment on alexander-li's answer, just add this line in your Makefile :

```
TweakName_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit
```

and add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` to your `Tweak.xm` file.

And please, just learn how to code before launching yourself in Theos development. It's not the easiest environment but there are a lot of pages who can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a UITapGestureRecognizer as a UIView parameter.

If you are trying to add a gesture recognizer,

```
[content addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

If you are trying to add a subview, you need to initialize a UIView object or a subclass of it. However, it seems you are trying to add a gesture recognizer.

Comment: When I fixed that it was replaced by another error that I pasted below. Do you think that you can help me with it.    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UITapGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Tweak.xm.28249181.o
  
 
  "_UIWindowLevelStatusBar", referenced from:
      _logos_method$_ungrouped$SBPowerDownController$orderFront(SBPowerDownController*, objc_selector*) in Tweak.xm.28249181.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1                 and a lot more but i couldn't add that much